# Need help explaining the following program

Tags: assembly, disassembly

Hi I am in the process of dissembling a program and I Can't seem to determine what this part of the program is meant to do. I understand that eax is a register and push eax places it onto the stack etc, but what does push offset aTaskmgr do?

An explanation would be most appreciated.

```
.text:00404867 loc_404867:                             ; CODE XREF: .text:00404870j
.text:00404867                 mov     cx, [eax]
.text:0040486A                 add     eax, 2
.text:0040486D                 test    cx, cx
.text:00404870                 jnz     short loc_404867
.text:00404872                 sub     eax, edx
.text:00404874                 sar     eax, 1
.text:00404876                 jz      loc_404927
.text:0040487C                 lea     ecx, [esp+1389Ch]
.text:00404883                 push    ecx
.text:00404884                 call    __wcslwr
.text:00404889                 push    offset aTaskmgr ; "taskmgr"
.text:0040488E                 push    eax
.text:0040488F                 call    _wcsstr
.text:00404894                 add     esp, 0Ch
.text:00404897                 test    eax, eax
.text:00404899                 jnz     short loc_404917
.text:0040489B                 lea     edx, [esp+1389Ch]
.text:004048A2                 push    edx
.text:004048A3                 call    __wcslwr
.text:004048A8                 push    offset aProcexp ; "procexp"
.text:004048AD                 push    eax
.text:004048AE                 call    _wcsstr
.text:004048B3                 add     esp, 0Ch
.text:004048B6                 test    eax, eax
.text:004048B8                 jnz     short loc_404917
.text:004048BA                 lea     eax, [esp+1389Ch]
.text:004048C1                 push    eax
.text:004048C2                 call    __wcslwr
.text:004048C7                 push    offset aRegedit ; "regedit"
.text:004048CC                 push    eax
.text:004048CD                 call    _wcsstr
.text:004048D2                 add     esp, 0Ch
.text:004048D5                 test    eax, eax
.text:004048D7                 jnz     short loc_404917
.text:004048D9                 lea     ecx, [esp+1389Ch]
.text:004048E0                 push    ecx
.text:004048E1                 call    __wcslwr
.text:004048E6                 push    offset aMsconfig ; "msconfig"
.text:004048EB                 push    eax
.text:004048EC                 call    _wcsstr
.text:004048F1                 add     esp, 0Ch
.text:004048F4                 test    eax, eax
.text:004048F6                 jnz     short loc_404917
.text:004048F8                 lea     edx, [esp+1389Ch]
.text:004048FF                 push    edx
.text:00404900                 call    __wcslwr
.text:00404905                 push    offset aCmd_exe ; "cmd.exe"
.text:0040490A                 push    eax
.text:0040490B                 call    _wcsstr
.text:00404910                 add     esp, 0Ch
.text:00404913                 test    eax, eax
.text:00404915                 jz      short loc_404920
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like nasty Windows code - seems to be converting a target Unicode string to lower case and then searching it for strings such as "taskmgr", "regedit", etc. Might be something from a malware scanner ?

Comment: Your disassembler was friendly enough to print the string as comment. As such, `push offset aTaskmgr` just pushes the address of the string `taskmgr` to the stack, in this case as an argument to `_wcsstr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this piece of code appears to be doing is first counting characters in a string, looking for a null character (two bytes in this case). It is a "wide" string - that is, 16-bit unicode based on the fact that it is incrementing eax by two each time around the loop. It is storing the length in eax, and while we can't see it, it looks like edx has a pointer to the beginning of the string. edx is subtracted from eax to turn eax from a pointer to a length count.

The rest of the code you provided us uses wcsstr, which is a function that looks for one wide string in another wide string, returning the location at which it is found. It is making comparisons with various provided strings, and when it finds a match by testing eax to see if it is non-zero (test eax, eax ; jnz...) it jumps to the code just after what you provided for us.

It appears to be traversing a list of processes based on the strings it is comparing. I am sure the surrounding code would make the rest of this clearer.

I hope this helps.

Comment: first paragraph: null character or "terminating null", not null *byte*.

Comment: Good catch, Peter. Mea culpa.

Comment: You can and should edit your answer to improve it when people point things out.  I sometimes just edit old answers myself, but it's more typical on SO for people to just leave a comment like I did, esp. for new posts where the poster is probably still around.  Welcome to SO, BTW. :)

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I'll fix it now.